# How do I access AWS secret keys on my client side securely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My client side is hosted on Amplify. The Amplify env variables are not safe for secrets so I took a look at SSM. The issue is that, to get to these keys I need to initiate a SecretsManagerClient, which requires credentials that should also be kept safe.

Is my only option here to use an .env file with dotenv?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the secret keys?

Comment: I have user pool credentials on the front end @DMalan

Comment: You have them or you want to get them? It's not a good idea to get secret keys from the frontend at all because an attacker could steal them. Hence why I'm asking what you're trying to achieve. There might be a better way.

Comment: I want to connect the oidc-react library with my user pool. Now I am just hard-coding my user pool details in the configuration of oidc-react, so I want a secure way to fetch that data instead of hard-coding @DMalan